# How to validate classification model with ordinal information

Tags: r, machine-learning, validation, naive-bayes

I have a Naive Bayes model that predicts 3 classes. As you increase each class it means that the condition is more severe. 0 means no condition, 1 is concern and 2 is that they have the condition. I have a model built but I am not sure how to correctly validate the accuracy.

Since 2 is further away from 0 it is less bad if a model classifies a 2 as a 1 instead of a zero. This means that my raw accuracy score is not completely correct.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare the inverse of the distance. Say we use the absolute value, meaning $distance(x,y) = | x-y|$.

The inverse of the distance from $0$ to $2$, e.g. $\frac{1}{|2-0|} = 0.5$, but from $1$ to $2$ is $1$. You just need to be careful when computing the ditance of a class to itself, setting it always to $0$, for example.

Comment: That makes sense when using that to validate,  would I compute the distance from the actual - predicted and use that to validate? Wouldn't that just be an error term?

Comment: It would just be an error if you're computing it for your training data. For a validation you simply compute it using you validation set .You can see my suggestion as a weighting for the mismatches, that gives a higher weight to the mismatches the user (you) consider more relevant.